# Dismissible ListTile text overlay

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I would like to have my ListTile content going behind the white background, just like the `ListTile.tileColor` on swipe.

I don't see this so much as a problem, but I would like to now if there is a way to fix it.

[image: Dismissible ListTile swiping left]

My Dismissible widget, with ListTile:

```
//For testing porpuses, removed some styling.

Dismissible(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  background: Container(
    decoration:
        BoxDecoration(color: cinzaIcone.withOpacity(0.5), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
  ),
  child: ListTile(
    //tileColor: cinza,
    tileColor: Colors.grey,
    dense: true,
    minLeadingWidth: 10,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
    leading: SizedBox(
      width: 1,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.circle,
          color: Colors.orange,
          size: 15,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    title: Text(
      //servico.nome,
      "CONTRAPISO - SOLEIRAS",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.blue),
    ),
    subtitle: Row(
      children: [
        Text(
          //DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(servico.dataInicio),
          "12-03-2021",    
          //style: dataServico,
        ),
        Text(
          ' até ',
          //style: dataServico,
        ),
        Text(
          //DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(servico.dataTermino),
          "17-03-2021",
          //style: dataServico,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: You can use the margin property, like put your dismissible inside a container with side margins to limit the width available to dismiss. Can you try this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some months, I realized that wrapping Dismissible with `ClipRRect` widget and passing `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEgde` solves it.

```
ClipRRect(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  child: ...
)
```

Comment: This is pure gold.

Comment: Nice.. this work